# Any production experience with DRDB dual primary?

Tags: network-attached-storage, drbd

In order to avoid having to setup a NAS system, I am considering the possibility of setting up a dual-primary with DRBD to handle RAID1 over IP.

Concerning filesystems, I know of OCFS and GFS as distributed filesystem. I am leaning towards OCFS as that seems like the more reliable option.

Do you have any production experience with such a system ? Am I heading towards trouble ? What should I expect/plan ?

Comment: With what protcol do you want to provide your NAS service and why do you need the dual primary mode for this?

Comment: NAS would be NFS. I need it for redundancy  :)

Comment: And you want to run a NFS-server on both sides with the same ip (else the NFS-handle for the same file will be different on both nodes)? Then you need a load-balancer in front of that construction. For NFS you should rather fail over (active/passive) and run halv of the nfs-exports on one side, the other one on the other side.